# Errors in R.java (android studio) after compilation

Tags: java, android

I am new to `Android Studio` and with the new version, I am facing some serious issues. Every time I try to compile any `android package`, I get the following errors:

### These errors are indicated in `R.java`- which is not supposed to be edited externally.

```
Error:(1452, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1452, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1452, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1453, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1453, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1453, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1454, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1454, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1454, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1455, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1455, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1455, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1456, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1456, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1456, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1457, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1457, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1457, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1458, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1458, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1458, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1459, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1459, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1459, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Please let me know a possible solution. Earlier, I was facing an `encoding incompatibility error`, which I fixed and then dropped to this problem.

Comment: Delete your generated files and recompile. If the error is still there then there is an error inside your code and the R errors will be resolved when the code is fixed inside the other xml files/etc

Comment: Could you please clarify? I tried to delete the generated files and then check but the issue is still there. I am clueless about which file generated error as this is a basic activity that contains a button operation.

Comment: Could you try "Build" -> "Clean Project" ?

Comment: Try looking through all of your resources, your problem is probably inside one of your xml files.  (Maybe check that button xml file?)

Comment: I tried Build->Clean Project but no success :(

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I deleted the lines and files which caused error (at XML files and drawabale). Then, I clicked on Build-Clean. It works.